Blazor interactive server authentication
Using this interaction mode, I cannot authenticate in any way. The last thing I tried was sending a request via HttpClient. The cookie is generated and added in the browser, but I still remain unauthorized.
Please tell me what to do. Other mode of operation Blazor, I am not interested. There at validation of data, there is a reloading of the page, I do not need it. Thank you.
Login.razor:
<div class="row">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div class="section-description contact-form">
        <EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="Authenticate">
            <label class="errorMessage" style="display:@Display">@ErrorMessage</label>
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <div class="text-left">
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Model.Email" class="errorMessage" />
                <label for="Email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                <InputText @bind-Value="Model.Email" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-left">
                <ValidationMessage For="() => Model.Password" class="errorMessage" />
                <label for="Password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <InputText type="Password" @bind-Value="Model.Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <button class="btn button-game" type="submit">
                    <span class="button-game-bg-left"></span>
                    <span class="button-game-bg-mid">
                        <span>Enter</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="button-game-bg-right"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>



@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("/lobby");
        }
    }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    LoginViewModel Model { get; set; } = new();

    async Task Authenticate()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:7051/api/auth", Model);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Lobby");
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle error response
        }
    }
}

AccountController:
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<User> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [Route("api/auth")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Not valid password");
            }
        }
    }

Tried everything.
Going to see a solution with the mode of operation:
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer

If your controller and blazor pages are in the same project (both using localhost:7051 )
You could visit "https://localhost:7051/api/auth" directly, then signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync will generate a signin cookie for the under domain localhost:7051 in the browser cookie storage. That cookie will make "httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" in the domain localhost:7051 being true.
But you are using httpclient to call the auth endpoint. The cookie will be generate to the "httpclient". This is useless and the cookie has nowhere to be saved. So httpcontext cannot find the cookie and will never  be authenticated.
As a matter of fact, you should implement authenticationstateprovider to save the authentication status and user infos for blazor front-end. And only in this way you could make your controller and blazor pages in seperate projects. (Not in same domain). If they are using different domain, the backend auth endpoinet shouldn't use signinasync(because generate a cookie for backend domian is useless for front-end). Instead, this endpoint should return a token. Then the front-end blazor pages will use httpclient to get this token to set authenticationstate.
Reference: https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

Thank you for your reply. I know about tokens, but I don't want to use them, it's easier for me to use React than Blazor. I've already moved the authorization part to MVC and use AJAX to work on the client with pages.
